# Send email before role expiration

Tags: users

after long searching and many attempts I definitely need your help.

On the website I am currently working on, people can buy a "Participant" role for 1 year.
I'm using ubercart to handle the purchasing process.

I am trying to set up an automatic email which is sent when the Participant role is about to expire. Lets say 1 month before.

I know there is the Role module in UberCart, but I really don't like it and I also think it is not flexible enough. I also know about the User Expire module, but I am not sure I can do what I want to with it.

I was trying to create a Rule which:
- runs on every Cron run
- scan all the users Expiry Date field 
- send an email to all the user with expiration closer than 1 month

Please give me some help...I am really out of ideas.

I hope I am missing a very easy way to implement it.

Thank you in advance,
guidout

Comment: How you are setting role expiration, custom code or `Role Expire` module

Comment: custom code. A Computed Field checks the last purchase date of the user and outputs the expiration date...

Comment: Then why can't you implement `hook_cron()` and do your logic there, instead of rules.

Comment: because I dont know how to do it and also I hoped there was something easier and less time consuming...

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any module which can help you do that, but doing what you want using `hook_cron()` is not that difficult.

Comment: thanks wolverine. can you point me some good resources where to learn how to use hooks? I know there are tons of material out there, I am just asking if you know a good place where to start from...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a custom module, implement `hook_cron()`, it is nothing but a function which will be called whenever cron runs.

Here is an [article](http://www.wintercreative.com/blog/2014/04/07/drupal-hooks-explained.html) explaining what are hooks.

For code reference install [examples](https://www.drupal.org/project/examples) module.

1. Implement `hook_cron()`
2. Load all the instance of the computed field, where you store the expiry date

   - Either you can directly query the database using `db_select()`
   - Or, use `field_attach_load()` to load only that field instances, instead of loading whole user object. [Here](http://timonweb.com/loading-only-one-field-from-an-entity-or-node) is an example of how to use `field_attach_load()`.
3. Check the expiry date.

   - Send a mail using `drupal_mail()` if the role is going to expire.

Note: You probably want this cron to run only once a day, for that install `Elysia Cron` and configure this hook to run once everyday by 12:00 am.

Comment: thank you very much for your time. I will try this way. I wanna wait a few days before setting this question as answered...just to see if somebody else has a "faster" idea...thanks again

Comment: I ended up making the custom module as you suggested. thanks